# How to use recursive CTE for calculating SUM of a field value hierarchically in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `tbSale` with these columns:

```
[CustomerCode] [bigint] NULL,
[SaleNum] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[time] [char](8) NULL,
[date] [char](8) NULL,
[PreviousSaleNum] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
```

And another table `tbSaleDetails` with these columns:

```
[SaleNum] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
[ProductCode] [bigint] NULL,
[price] [bigint] NULL,
[code] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[count] [float] NULL
```

`[SaleNum]` in `tbSale` is the primary key, also `[code]` in `tbSaleDetails` is the primary key. There is a relationship between `tbSale.[SaleNum]` and `tbSaleDetails.[SaleNum]`; also there is a relationship between `tbSale.[SaleNum]` and `tbSale.[PreviousSaleNum]` which relates a sale to previous sales for a specific customer.

**QUESTION**: I want to show all rows with calculation of `SUM(tbSaleDetails.[price] * tbSaleDetails.[count])` for all sales and their previous sales which is given in `[PreviousSaleNum]`. I need a recursive CTE to do this (I suppose). But I don't know how to do it. I can't use `SUM()` inside recursive statement of CTE because it throws error.

Comment: you say you need a recursive CTE, what for? as fare as i understand, you want the current and the previous amount.

Comment: Should the rows only include the most recent sale (in a sale thread) with the total of that sale and all sales previous? Or are you looking for every individual sale and all previous sales up to that point in time of the sale thread (like running totals)?

Comment: Will you ever have more than 32,767 sales in a "sale thread?"

Comment: @Aツ I want SUM of current sale plus SUM of the previous sale which is given in [PreviousSaleNum], the [PreviousSaleNum] itself has the field [PreviousSaleNum] and so on. that's why i need a recursive CTE.

Comment: @8kb: every row includes SUM of [price]*[count] for current row + SUM of  [price]*[count] for previous sale which is given in [PreviousSaleNum] field. [PreviousSaleNum] has relationship to [SaleNum] and both are in the same table. In other word there is relationship in tbSale to itself. the result i'm looking for is a table including [SaleNum], [CustomerCode], [time], [date], SUM([price]*[count]). in this table SUM([price]*[count]) is NOT only calculating sum of current row, but also plus sum of previous sale which is given in [PreviousSaleNum].

Comment: @8kb: it should do it by recursive CTE until [PreviousSaleNum] gets NULL.

Comment: Currently i don't have more than 32,767 sales in a "sale thread" but in future i will.